# Need to find position of maximum of three numbers

Tags: java

I am trying to find the position of the maximum of three numbers that the user inputs. I do not know how to find the position of this but I can find max of the numbers.

Here is the task:
**Here is the method named getNumberOfMaxParam that takes three integer numbers and returns the position of the first maximum in the order of the method parameters.**

**UPDATE: I am trying to compare the int a.b.c but I get This method must return a result of type int error**
Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class App {
  
  
  public static int getNumberOfMaxParam(int a, int b, int c) {

    int firstMax = Math.max(a, b);

    int highMax = Math.max(firstMax, c);
    
    if (a == highMax) {
      System.out.println("1");
    
    } else if (b == highMax) {
      System.out.println("2");
    
    } else if (c == highMax) {
      System.out.println("3");
    
    } else {
      return highMax;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    final int a = scanner.nextInt();
    final int b = scanner.nextInt();
    final int c = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.print(getNumberOfMaxParam(a, b, c));
  }
}
```

Now how do I find the position?

Comment: sounds like a homework for me... What have you achieved so far? What is the expected output, and what you get instead?

Comment: Now you know which one is the max, you should be able to compare with the inputs: `if a eq max then first`, `if b eq max then second`, etc.

Comment: save inputs in an array, it could be easier

Comment: @sp00m  Thanks, but are you suggesting I use branching because I am using branching statements and it seems that I am getting an "This method must return a result of type int" error. I am going to update my code to show what it looks like now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `Stream` api. You simply pass an array of values in the order you want. Then create an IntStream of the values and find the max. Then create an IntStream of the indices and find the first value in the array to see if it matches max, and return the index.

```java
private static int getIndexOfMax(int... values) {
    int max = IntStream.of(values).max().orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);
        
    return IntStream.range(0, values.length)
            .filter(index -> values[index] == max)
            .findFirst().orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);
}
```

```java
int index = getIndexOfMax(1, 2, 3);

assert index == 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**PS. It could be controversial if you supply same value for multiple inputs.** 



public static int getNumberOfMaxParam(int a, int b, int c) {
    
        int firstMax = Math.max(a, b);
    
        int highMax = Math.max(firstMax, c);
        return (highMax == a ? 1 : (highMax == b ? 2 : 3 );
      }
```